Apprendre le français : où aller maintenant?
Bonjour. Je m'appele Silvio. je suis arrivé récemment à France (j'habite ici et je vivra ici pendant au moins 3 ans).
Switching to English, sorry.
My french is very very basic and I came to live here without planning. It was something that just happened and I didn't had the time to properly dive into the language before moving.
I am Brazilian, which makes understanding french quite easy, specially for reading, because portuguese is very similar to the french grammar, at least in most of the situations and structures. Mais, pour parler, mon vocabuleire est très, très basique et limité, et je ne connais personne ici: which makes it even harder to practice. But I am trying and I am studying and I want a lot to properly learn the language.
So my questions is as simple as that: where do I go now?
I mean, I know the basics. But I need to practice. I finished yesterday these playlist:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DENA9FONsoQ&list=PLqNemMi0_-saDnATbSelpqD0Dx0AvfbO_
it is very short, very interesting and helped me to at least be able to speak the basics and understand a little. But I am living an environment where I need to speak in a more advanced level as quick as I can (it is job stuff). But since I am studying alone, I am kind of lost. I am to do everything at the same time and I am not sure where to go or what should be the next step.
I know that grammar is important, but learning it theoretically without practice won't help, but practicing is complicated and even if I have time to do it I won't be able to speak if I don't have vocabulary to put words in the __________ .....
I would appreciate some help, some guidance, some light from people who passed for some similar experience before. I just don't want to lose my head trying "to be fluent in a week or I will die", you know.

Dimitri, please click on the [[ressources]] tag, there are over 30 questions that will give you resources for learning French.  I'm sorry to vote to close this as a duplicate, so please stick around for specific questions as you learn.  Courage continue !

As the others have said, there are lots of places to start. Personally, I find the Easy French videos a great way to introduce students to "street French", not overly careful, just casual and natural, with the benefit of subtitles in both French and English. https://www.youtube.com/easyfrench

@livresque is not a problem, the question is indeed a duplicate. I should have made a better effort in looking at the forum before openning a question. That day I was a little desperate and suddenly came across with this forum hehe thanks and no problem

@LukeSawczak thanks for the link, very interesting.
